# Rails form partial rendering of one model in the view of another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms, partial-views

I am working on building a rails app and right now I am struggling with displaying a from partial from one model in the view of another model.

So I have models `User` and `Goal`.  A user can have many goals, and a goal has one user.

In the show view for a `User`, I list out that user's goals.  I am trying to display a jQuery dialog that allows you to edit the goal.  I have a form_for partial for the goal that I modified based on initial scaffolding

```
<%= form_for([@user, @goal]) do |f| %>
...
<% end %>
```

I am trying to create a `<div>` in the `users#show` view that can render that form, but I can't figure out how (or if it is even possible) to pass the correct parameters to the form_for partial

```
<%= div_for(goal, :class => "dialog edit", :title => "Edit Goal") do %>
   <%= render :partial => 'goals/form' %>
<% end %>
```

which gives me `undefined method 'model_name' for NilClass` error, leading me to believe that the form_for doesn't know what @user and @goal should be.

My controller for the user#show is like so

```
def show
   @user = User.find(params[:id])
end
```

and for goals#edit

```
def edit
   @goal = @user.goals.find(params[:id])
end
```

Routes looks like this

```
resources :users do
   resources :goals
end
```

What do I need to adjust to display the edit goal form in the `user#show` view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be  you have to have the partial inside user views or send parameter as local hash if you are trying with goals/form

Comment: I am thinking that the local hash makes sense, but I can't figure out how to do that.  I have tried the `:locals` argument in the render call but can't get that to work

Comment: <%= render :partial => 'goals/form' :locals=>{:data=>@goal} %>.So we can access the variable data in form partial file

Comment: Yep.  That's basically it.  Finally got it to work. the problem was that i was using

Comment: Sorry, accidentally submitted that one early.

Yep.  That's basically it.  Finally got it to work. I think the problem was that i was using `<%= render 'goals/form', :locals => {:goal, goal} %>`.  I don't think you can mix the shorthand and full form notation because `<%= render 'goals/forms', :goal => goal %>` seems to work as well

Answer (score -1):

I had to make a small syntax change, but it worked for me.

```
<%= render 'goals/form', :goal => @goal %>
```

Comment: Please explain what the error in the OP's code is, and why this syntax works. As it stands, it's difficult to tell what the new code does, and OP is unlikely to return to this question to confirm this works.